# Generate Insert out of an object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to generate an Insert SQL query out of a bean instance? maybe using Hibernate code?

for example:

```
@Table(name = "tbl_a")
class A{

   @Column(name = "col_a")
   int a;

   @Column(name = "col_b")
   int b;
}
```

to INSERT INTO tbl_a (col_a,col_b) VALUES (avalue,bvalue)

So if I will provide it with an A instacne which has a = "val" and b = 5 I will get:

INSERT INTO tbl_a (col_a,col_b) VALUES ('val',5)
??

**EDIT**

It seems I am not understood well so let me explain: I know how to persist with Hibernate. What I want is the actual class that generated the SQL query itself. The same query that will eventually be committed to the DB. But I need the Query string. Meaning, that I need a tool (or use Hibernate's class) which gets an object and returns a simple string containing the SQL query. (not in a log).

I hope it's is better now.

Thanks, Idob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so there is no tool which gets an object and returns a simple string containing the SQL query.But you can use `getQueryString()` method of **Query** class. you will get whole **HQL string** except the runtime parameters.
If you are interested in **SQL string** then you can enable **DEBUG** on the log4j system of Hibernate and use JDBCAppender or some custom Appender to capture the native SQL.

Anyway this option will make your app very slow (hibernate generates a lot of debug).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(new A())` to directly insert your instance. The executed SQL will look similar to how you described it. You can test this by turning on hibernate debugging by doing `hibernate.show_sql=true`

Comment: No. I dont want to save and look at the log. what I Want is get the query itself in runtime. the actual query string. I know how to persist with Hibernate.